KDE Plasma 5 black screen on boot
I have a HP EliteBook 840 with Kubuntu 24.04 LTS
It was running fine however today I ran sudo reboot nowfrom inside a tmux terminal. Now I get a black screen upon ubuntu boot.
I can boot into bios.
What are the recommended troubleshooting steps? I would like to not damage the OS.
I've already tried booting into grub by pressing rshift. It seems like something was going on due to the screen lighting up a couple times more but I cannot see a grub menu.
The disk is not LUKS encrypted. I don't think I ran apt updates during the time the laptop was on & nothing else was being installed.
One thing that does stand out: The Anytype app showed strange behaviour not being able to be opened at all (leading me to restart). This has happened before with this app but never caused a black screen.


With the force shut down you did it looks like the app that crashed might have left your OS in an unstable state.

Okay a bit odd, I wanted to try and chroot into my system from a live usb but after booting directly to the usb my login screen came up (black screen went away) & the system works fine for now.
